# How to get around "Name too long for LOGINREC field (severity 2)" without changing login parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, yii2

I am working on a PHP, Yii2 app that connects to a third party SQL Server database using login credentials provided by the third party.

Unfortunately, the password is more than 30 characters long, which is unsupported by the PDO MSSQL driver. The password cannot be changed.

Is there a workaround?

Error when connecting to the database is as follows.

```
    SQLSTATE[HY000] Name too long for LOGINREC field (severity 2)
```

Comment: Nice, making passwords less secure by design :) I've seen things like that. Have you tried to send only first 30 characters of the password? Sometimes it works

Comment: @Bizley Thanks. Yes, shortening the password to 30 characters is able to attempt the connection, but for obvious reasons doesn't connect as the password is incorrect.